# "As well" instead of "Either" in a specific case

Tags: grammaticality

Would it be considered grammatically correct to use "as well" instead of either in this sentence?

"No one was asking you ***either***"

or is it just a flow issue?

Comment: As a new poster to this site, please take the time to finish reading the [Tour], and then carefully read the Help on asking questions. If you are not a native speaker of English your question may be more suitable for SE English Language Learners, but first you need to explain what is intended by, or the context of, adding the word “either” at the end of a sentence that appears complete already.

Answer (score 1):

No. You specify "'as well' *instead of* 'either'" (emphasis mine). So --- if I understand you correctly --- you are asking whether substituting "as well" for "either" yields a grammatical sentence *which means the same thing*.

It doesn't. "Either" in the sense used here is a [negative polarity item](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item#In_English) licensed by the negative word "No one". So your sentence might occur in a context like this:

No one was asking *me*. No one was asking *you*, either.

Now the sentence "No one was asking you as well" is grammatically correct. However, "as well" is a positive polarity item. If it was supposed to relate to "no one" in the same way as in your example sentence, then it would have to be a negative polarity item, and we get your example sentence again. So "as well" must relate to something else. Perhaps "No one was asking you as well" means "No one was asking you in addition to asking somebody else".